# In my unit of work, I can not use DbEntityValidationException class with Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, implementation

I have to regenerate:

```cs
public void Commit(bool validateSave = true)
{
    try
    {
        if (!validateSave)
            DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

        Guid tranId = Guid.Empty;

        List<object> addeds = new List<object>();
        List<Log> modifiedAndDeleteds = new List<Log>();

        Logger logger = new Logger();

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logEnabled"]))
        {
            tranId = Guid.NewGuid();
            addeds = this.DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(s => s.State == EntityState.Added).Select(s => s.Entity).ToList();
            modifiedAndDeleteds = logger.GetLogsOfNonAddeds(this.DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(s => s.State == EntityState.Modified || s.State == EntityState.Deleted), tranId);
        }

        DbContext.SaveChanges();

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logEnabled"]))
        {
            logger.LogAddeds(addeds, tranId);
            logger.LogNonAddeds(modifiedAndDeleteds);
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
#if DEBUG
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                    validationError.PropertyName,
                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
#endif

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!validateSave)
            DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

This code in my unit of work class with Entity Framework Core 7 but I get a `DbEntityValidationException`. I tried many more alternative classes for `DbEntityValidationException` but couldn't solve the problem.

I am using a custom logger class, because of I am trying to convert framework and I can not change database format etc. so I have to implement all code in EF Core 7.

Please help

I couldn't find any good solution

Comment: EF Core does not implement any validation by design